# What does P|a means?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

In the proof for the existence of unlimited prime numbers, i saw the following

let n be the number of prime numbers as P1,P2,P3,.......Pn
 let a = P1P2P3....Pn+1
a > Pn and a is not a prime number 
a should have a prime factor 
let P be it
P|a ----> 1
but P|a-1 ----->2
1 & 2 ->  P|1 
but 1 doesn't have a factor ........
and the proof follows

but i didn't understand the symbol P|a
what does P|a means? please somebody explain me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $P$ is a divisor of $a$.

Comment: if its the divisor of a then how do  and a-1 have the same divisor

Comment: Because $a-1$ is the product of all primes.

Comment: a is the product of all prime numbers no

Comment: Of course $a$ is not. $a-1$ is.

Comment: but we assume a to be the multiplication of prime numbers

Comment: No. We assume $a=P_1\cdots P_n\color{red}{+1}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26234/discussion-between-ampatishan-arun-and-eclipse-sun).

Answer (score 1):

P|a means P divides a.For P|a we can also write this as Pc=a where c is a constant.It simply means that $$P*c=a$$ or P is a factor of a.

Answer (score 0):

It means $p$ is a divisor of $a$, i.e $a$ leaves a remainder of $0$ when divided by $p$. You can also write $a \equiv 0 \text{ mod }p$.